# How to destructure a Json array object to use in my react component?

Tags: json, reactjs

[image]I have sent a http get request and have received an JSON object as follows: [image]

How can I destructure the json array and convert it into an array in my react component?

Comment: Well, this is an array. Your component is in which position of the array? Can you write here the content of this array?

Comment: Hi, I've added the screenshot and I have 32 items in the array with properties which I would like to access. Are you able to show how I can extract each element and their properties to be placed in an array which I can map and use in my react component? Thank you so much!

Comment: `array.map(({propertyname})=>propertyname) === [propertyval1,propertyval2,propertyval3...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, do you have an array of objects. It's no big deal my friend, you extract it on both of this ways, choose the one that fits your needs.

---

1st way, extracting only elements:

```
const [element1, element2, element3, ...rest] = carpak;
```

This way you will extract the three first elements to the variables above and the rest of the array will be placed in the variable `rest`.

---

2nd way, extracting properties of the elements in array:

```
const [{
    id: id1,
    latitude: la1,
    longitude: lo1,
    ...rest: rest1,
}, {
    id: id2,
    latitude: la2,
    longitude: lo2,
    ...rest: rest2,
}] = carpak;
```

In this example we accessed the first and the second element's properties. But we didn't care about the rest of the array of elements. Note that we are using some alias for the variables because if we don't do so, the variables would be used twice and we would have a compilation problem.

---

3rd way, extracting elements and properties from array:

```
const [{
    id,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    ...restProperties,
}, element2, ...restElements] = carpak;
```

Now we have accessed the first element's properties, the entire second element and the rest of the elements in the array. Now we don't need aliases because we are only using the variables once.

Hope any of these help you man. In addition I would like to recommend you the next two links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/